# Convergence of improper integral involving exponential

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

How to show that $\int_0^{\infty} e^{\lambda x}x^{r} dx$ converges when $\lambda$ is negative and $r$ a positive integer?

Comment: It doesn't (without some assumptions on $r$)

Comment: r is just a positive integer

Comment: I tried to calculate the integral from 0 to b which is a very long summation and attempted to calculate the limit when b is infinity. So I was thinking maybe if there is a function which dominates $exp(\lambda x)x^r$ and such that the integral from 0 to $\infty$ converges then I am done!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substitution $u = - \lambda x$, with which:
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{\lambda x} x^r d x 
   = (- \lambda)^{-r} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} u^r d u
   = (- \lambda)^{-r} \Gamma(r + 1)
$$
See the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function). If $r$ is a positive integer, derivation by parts show this is $(- \lambda)^{-r} r!$.

Comment: Thanks, and the answer turns out to be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Hint (assuming $r\in\mathbb{N}$): Everything is well-behaved on finite intervals, so you only need to check the limiting behavior. But, note that for sufficiently large $x4

$$e^{-\lambda x}=\frac{1}{1+\lambda x+\frac{\lambda}{2} x^2+\cdots}\leqslant \frac{1}{1+\cdots +\frac{\lambda}{(r+1)!}x^{r+1}}$$

Comment: Oh I see, this is the kind of proof I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You probably know some "standard limits", for example that
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x^r}{e^{ax}}=0$$
for $a > 0$. Hence $x^r < e^{-\lambda x/2}$ if $x$ is large enough (take $a=-\lambda/2$).

Comment: I know this limit, I just don't see how the integral woukd converge if you have that. Do you mean, the function goes to zero at infinity implies the integral converges? so what about integral to infinity of 1/sqrt(x), I know it does not converge. Tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Max Since $r>0$, your integrand is bounded near $0$, so you only have to worry about large $x$, where the integrand is smaller than $e^{-\lambda x/2}\cdot e^{\lambda x} = e^{\lambda x/2}$. You can easily find an antiderivative to see that the larger integral converges.